# How to post an example for documentation

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-examples

I'm trying to post a new example on documentation when I wrote significant material to post and added some images Than I tried to submit that example. I pressed <kbd>Submit for Review</kbd> button but an error comes up saying:

> Title is required.

check the image below

[image]

However I Wrote the title for that. As
[image]

So I'm wondering how to post a new example for documentation.
Need your help.

Comment: I can't find the draft listed on your profile. Are you still having issues?